# In email_operator of airflow if we are giving same email id in to and cc, it's not working?

Tags: airflow

In email_operator of airflow if we are giving same email id in to and cc. it's not working.

```
t_email_success = email_operator.EmailOperator(
            task_id='t_email_success',
            to='abc@sample.com',
            cc= 'abc@sample.com',
            subject='report file',
            html_content="""Hi Team,<br><br>

                                        sample email<br><br>

                                        Thanks & Regards,<br><br>
                                        """
        )
        t_email_success.execute(context=kwargs)
```

Comment: What does it write into the logs?

Comment: Hello @ SergiyKolesnikov, there is no Error, Task is runnings uccessfully but getting  WARNING - Failed to send out email with subject report file, error: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: and is it working when you have only the `to` field?

Comment: Yes @mucio , When we have only the to field. It's working.

Comment: and if they are equal no email is going out or just one?

Comment: @mucio, If they are equal No email is going out.